# Is this type of smooth function analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{C}$ be a $C^{\infty}$ application, such that for any $t_0\in (a,b)$ there is $g:(a,b)\to\mathbb{C}$, $g\in C^{\infty}((a,b)),\ g(t_0)\neq 0$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}^*$ such that: $f(t)=f(t_0)+(t-t_0)^m g(t), \ \forall\ t\in (a,b)$.

Is it true that $f$ is an analytic function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, let $f(t) = t^2 + e^{-1/t^2}, t\ne 0, f(0)=0.$ Then we know $f$ is not analytic on $\mathbb{R},$ because of the vanishing of all derivatives of $e^{-1/t^2}$ at $0.$

At $t_0=0,$ we have $$f(t)-f(0) = f(t) = t^2(1 + e^{-1/t^2}/t^2).$$ We know $e^{-1/t^2}/t^2,$ if defined to be $0$ at $0,$ is in $C^\infty(\mathbb {R}).$ So we have the desired representation at $0.$

If $t_0\ne 0,$ then $f$ is analytic in the interval $I=(t_0-|t_0|/2, t_0+|t_0|/2).$ Thus there exists an analytic $h$ on $I$ and $m> 0$ such that $$f(t) - f(t_0)= (t-t_0)^mh(t), \,\,h(t_0)\ne 0.$$ Define $g(t) = (f(t) - f(t_0))/(t-t_0)^m, t\ne t_0, g(t_0) = h(t_0).$ Then surely $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb {R}\setminus \{t_0\}).$ But we also have $g= h$ in $I.$ Therefore  $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb {R})$ and we have the desired representation for $f$ at $t_0.$